# Likely buyer of a specific brand

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, references, business-intelligence

I understand the concept of targeting likely buyers. It’s a pretty straightforward solution.

I’m trying to find some literature on identifying the likely buyers/purchasers of a specific brand.

I think this is a bit more challenging than the traditional propensity to purchase model because you can have many brands and you can also have very sparse data associated with a single brand.

I can’t find anything about this online. I’m wondering if anyone can share some research on the topic if there is any.